Isolating features in blender for easier 3D printing
If I were to scan my head and load it into blender, how would I isolate features (lips, clothing, etc) to make them easier to paint in a slicer?
Currently if I load a scan of my head into my slicer and then try to use the Paint Bucket to color it, it will all be the same color. If I try to use a paintbrush it would take forever to get all the details painted. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to turn all these different parts of the head into faces that I could then use a paint bucket with and color them faster.
I have an fdm printer that does multi-color prints and would like to be able to make multi-color busts and figures. I know how to do this kind of thing fusion 360 for a more regular object, but doing something more organic like a homan body/face is beyond what I know.
I've been told that blender can do it but I cannot find anything relevant on YouTube.
Thank you for any help.

Blender doesn’t have a magic smart select tool like what you’re thinking of. There are various techniques you can pick up to help you select certain parts of a mesh, but without being able to come up with techniques on the specific model in question, I can send you to the Blender manual page on mesh edit selecting at least. Ideally, your 3D scanner would supply the color as an image texture. Double check if it is able to or not.
